# Auto-format XML file to 'Android Studio style'

Tags: xml, netbeans, netbeans-8

Is it possible to enable XML autoformatting to Android Studio look-like? I mean, one property in one line. For example :

*DEFAULT STYLE :*

```
<rootNode property1="abc" property2="abc" property3="abc" property4="abc" property5="abc" property6="abc" property7="abc" property8="abc">
    <children otherProperty1="abc" otherProperty2="abc" otherProperty3="220">
    </children>
</rootNode>
```

*FORMATTED STYLE:*

```
<rootNode 
    property1="abc" 
    property2="abc" 
    property3="abc" 
    property4="abc" 
    property5="abc" 
    property6="abc" 
    property7="abc" 
    property8="abc">
    <children 
        otherProperty1="abc" 
        otherProperty2="abc" 
        otherProperty3="220">
    </children>
</rootNode>
```

It's little annoying to search and change values in default format style.